# Failed command: WRITE DMA

Tags: boot, hardware, hard-drive

When I boot up my computer, it takes a long time and has a "failed command: WRITE DMA" error with other lines that looks like the command line, can anyone help me?

I replaced the 40 pin cable from my old Hard drive with an 80 pin cable and it didn't fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10? Can you reply with the output from 'df -T' please? At first it sounds like a bad controller. But there's this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/569680.

Comment: Or can you try using kernel 2.6.35-24?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/559319/

Comment: No swap at all?

Answer (score 2):

Open the disk utility and check the SMART diagnostics.  Run the long self test and make sure you do not have any offline, pending, or reallocated sectors.  If you do, then the drive is failing.  If you do not, then it could be a bad cable or controller.

Comment: The drive isn't failing.